# Does calling a ViewModel instance reset the LiveData?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

In Kotlin I'm using

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
```

To retrieve a ViewModel from the providers.

Inside my ViewModel I have something like this.

```
val liveChuchuData = MutableLiveData<DataChuchu>()
```

From my understanding this creates a final new variable of MutableLiveData right?

I remember when declaring MutableLiveDatas in ViewModel in Java, **we create a function and then check if the MutableLiveData is null** to only create it once.
So what if I have a fragment that will also use the same ViewModel instance.

```
val liveChuchuData = MutableLiveData<DataChuchu>()
```

Will that line cause the current data to be reset, once called in a fragment?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depends on what is the parent of your ViewModel. If parent is `Acivity` and in your `Fragment` you initialize your `ViewModel` with `getActivity()` instead of passing **this**, then you will reuse that `ViewModel`, but for example if you have two separate `Fragments` that initialize same `ViewModel` by passing **this** to `ViewModelProvider` then your `ViewModel` will have two separate instances and different data in them.

To have same data in `ViewModel` in two `Fragments`, you need to pass `getActivity();` to `ViewModelProvider` when creating your `ViewModel` instance.

---

That said, **YES**, it will cause your data to be reset if you use **this** when creating `ViewModel`.

---

Hope this helps. Good luck :)

Comment: awesome - thanks bro - works. Still feels like a patch on the problem by Google, not a well designed solution. Single responsibility principle broken

Comment: Hi, in my code, in same fragment , I have clear live data and set new live data when user search. Plz help me how to do clear live data?

Comment: @SAndroidD I suggest you to create a new question, because it is not related to current context.

Comment: I wont reset live data in same fragment